# гугл карта не отображается на телефоне после сборки apk

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Пишу приложение в Android studio с использованием Google Maps. Карты отображаются и работают на эмуляторе, но когда создаю релиз-apk и устанавливаю на телефон, то карты не отображаются. только фон и надпись GOOGLE внизу экрана. Делал все по инструкции. Выпустил API-key для релиз-версии. Но все равно не помогает. Очень нужна помощь. Заранее всем благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

А build variant вы точно выбрали release перед сборкой?! в скрипте правильно прописали параметры релизного ключа? Такое часто случается из-за несоответствия ключей, тест на внимательность))

Comment: Да, выбираю  release. По умолчанию так выставлено. В скрипте каком?